# MS Access and number of decimal places returned in calculations

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

This is not a formatting question.

I have recently found that doing a simple division in an MS Access (2010) query does not return the expected number of digits.  Even the simplest:
(3.1 + 3.1)/2 = 3.1

But MS Access returns 3.09999990463257

Yes, I can round and/or format the result to show a specified number of decimal places.  Also, in the example above, rounding would give me the true value of 3.1; however, my question is simply "why does MS Access do this?" rather than how to fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: That link will help you understand the issues involved with decimal math on a binary system.  But something else in your question surprises me.  The following Access 2010 query shows me 3.1 for Expr1 and -1 (True) for Expr2.  `SELECT (3.1+3.1)/2 AS Expr1, (3.1+3.1)/2=3.1 AS Expr2`  That does not agree with what you reported.

Comment: VBA often does some implicit rounding or "close enough" comparisons to try and be helpful. For example, `?(0.2 * 5.0) = 1.0` returns `True`, but `?((0.2 * 5.0) - 1.0) = 0.0` returns `False` because `?((0.2 * 5.0) - 1.0)` returns `5.55111512312578E-17`.

Comment: HansUp,  Thanks.  Indeed, the formula with actual numbers does return 3.1; So my apologies.  But, if a field is used and added to itself then divided by 2, the exact number is not returned unless it is a whole number.  I found this is true whether the field is data type Double or Single.

Answer (score 1):

Both

```
SELECT (3.1+3.1)/2 AS Result FROM tblFoo
```

in a query, and

```
Debug.Print (3.1 + 3.1)/2
```

in VBA return `3.1` for me.

Are you summing up values of data type **Single**? They have limited precision.